# Playing audio from a web plugin in Nativescript iOS WebView

Tags: nativescript

I came across a plugin that plays the sound of a given chord. This plugin was developed to be used in browsers. I have managed to implement it using Nativescript WebView on Android. The problem is that it is not working on iOs. Here is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    context = new AudioContext();
    function playChordSound(cho){
        window.cp.buildChordPlayer(cho, context).play();
    }
   </script>

    <button id="playChordBtn"></button>

    <script src="./lib/nativescript-webview-interface.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <!--        <script src="https://www.scales-chords.com/api/scales-chords-api.js"></script> -->
    <script src="./chordplayer/src/dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I have to set some permissions or load something before the plugin can use iOs WebView sound capabilities?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need any special permissions to play audio using default HTML5 audio controls. Can you create a Playground example where we can see the issue?

Comment: your path to the audio file maybe wrong in iOS. Can you post your code ?

Comment: Hi @Manoj, I've added some code to the question. As I mentioned before, on Android this code works fine.

Comment: I think chordplayer library may not loaded as expected into your WebView. Try to make sure the path is correct and it's loaded. Also try to setup a Playground, it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @Manoj thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate that. But all I need to know is if this line is right: AudioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext); It works on Android.